# setting the culture info in bing maps in Metro Style Apps

Tags: javascript, windows-8, bing-maps

I am working currently with Bing Maps in Windows 8 Metro Style Apps.

all works fine, except the fact that the site is always in a different language. now i wanted to set the culture info to fix it, but when i searched for it in google i didn't found something that could work.

I am using javascript as programming language.

has someone an idea how i could set the culture info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem like you , if you wish that bing map provide you data with the culture you wish , you must precise it in the REST request with the parameter culture : culture=culture_code.

See this example :

"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=" + me.location.latitude + "," + me.location.longitude + "&wp.1=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&**culture=fr-FR**&key=" + credentials

The response result must be in French Language